# Updating partial data in DB while fetching data should count as GET or PUT request in REST API

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

My class is to fetch current song info from Spotify api.

```
class GetCurrentSong(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        dict_song_info = get_song_from_spotify(user_session=self.request.session.session_key)

        if 'Error' in dict_song_info:
            return Response({dict_song_info['Error_Type']: dict_song_info['Error']}, status=dict_song_info['Status'])     

        # Update song name in database
        try:
            self.update_song_info_in_db(dict_song_info['name'])
        except Exception as ex:
            return Response({'Storage Error': 'Caanot persist current song info to database'}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

        return Response(dict_song_info, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Besides fetching song info and rendering to the frontend, I also need to update song name data in DB before rendering.

My question is: this function involves data update (no create new entries, just update existing data record). Does it still count as "Get"? Or actually, I should use "PUT" for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET vs PUT is about the semantics of the request, not the details of the implementation.

If I'm asking you for the current copy of a web page, that's a GET, *even if* your implementation needs to download information from somewhere else and write into your own local cache/database.

Comment: Just wondering what has REST to do with DB, it is in a completely different layer. Somehow people confuse REST with a CRUD HTTP database interface + anaemic domain model and they don't understand the definition of a webservice or the difference between services and databases...